# Passing a variable into rsync

Tags: bash, rsync

I have the following script:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 ...
 rsync -e 'ssh -i "$SSHKeyPath"'
```

The error is:

```
Warning: Identity file $SSHKeyPath not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

How can I get $SSHKeyGen evaluated before rsync gets called?

**UPDATE:**
fwiw, this is on OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions that I believe are easier:

- Use `ssh-agent(1)` to unlock the private portion of the key for `ssh(1)` processes as they need it. This is by far the easiest mechanism to use.
- Use `~/.ssh/config` to select a different private key based on hostname:

  ```
  host backuphost
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/different_key
  ```

Then there is no need to specify a key on the command line.

**Update**

Given that you're trying to separate the key from the individual user, this makes a lot more sense to me now. If you use another variable in `sh` you can make your original approach work:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh

SSHKeyPath=/home/sarnold/.ssh/id_rsa
KEYARG="ssh -i $SSHKeyPath"

rsync -e "$KEYARG" /tmp/pointless localhost:/tmp/new_pointless
$ ./foo.sh 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/sarnold/.ssh/id_rsa': 
skipping directory pointless
```

Comment: Unfortunately the goal is for the script to be portable. I think using those methods would require a bunch more code on the end-user's machine.

Comment: The second solution makes sense to me, but I get `Missing trailing-' in remote-shell command.`

Comment: Oh man, I've learned a good lesson tonight: output from `echo(1)` isn't always to be trusted. It might _look_ like `'ssh -i path'`, but when it got passed to `execve(2)` by `rsync(1)`, it was parsed into: `execve("/usr/bin/rsync", ["rsync", "-e", "'ssh", "-i", "/home/s...rsa'", "/tmp/..." ...)`. Obviously the shell quoting rules are more subtle than I recalled. Testing with actual `rsync(1)` let me get an actual working version, above.

Answer (score 0):

You're using single quotes, which cannot substitute variable name with it's value. It will be ok with douuble quotes.

For example

```
$> path_to_file="/tmp/file"; rsync -e "$( ssh -i "$path_to_file" )"
Warning: Identity file /tmp/file not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: I think your `$( ... )` is throwing off the solution -- it is executing `ssh` right then and there, rather than letting `rsync` execute `ssh`. Try replacing `rsync -e` with `echo hello` -- you'll still see output from `ssh`, even though it shouldn't be executed yet.

Comment: This solution results in `usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]`

Comment: See my funny comments above about the dangers of using `echo(1)` in testing. Hehe. But still, try this completely with hosts and paths and I think you'll see the `ssh(1)` isn't working right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rsync -e "ssh -i ""$SSHKeyPath"
```